# Using Backbone.Sync without specific model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, backbone.js

(Rails 3 + backbone 0.53)
I am fetching data from my API on "/payments" url and it returns different kinds of payment data.

So the user can for example delete, let's say a credit-card entry and it is synced backed to the server on

```
"/credit_cards".
```

The problem is that if I use Backbone.Sync with the syntax

```
Backbone.Sync('delete', @options.credit_cards.get('id'))
```

it gives me an "**A "url" property or function must be specified**" error.

This makes sense as the model e.g.:

```
@options.credit_cards.get('id')
```

does not exist in this case because credit_cards doesn't store any data. I just wanna do a standard DELETE with Backbone.sync á la

```
"/credit_cards/:id"
```

but just by specifying the id (which I receive from /payments) not the model (but the model/collection has the url...)

So my question is: 1.) 
is there a way in backbone to use backbone.sync without actually storing data in a collection/model, more like a simple ajax request with jQuery.
Example:

```
Backbone.Sync('delete', "specify_a_url_here_with/#{id}"))
```

instead of using Backbone.Sync & $.ajax requests mixed.

2.) does that make sense at all or is there a better alternative.

Thanks a lot! I really love SO! Hope the question isn't to weird. Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass "url" and "data" to Backbone.Sync in "options".

Backbone.sync(method, model, options) returns a $.ajax(params) where params.url and params.data reflect your model unless you exlicitly pass them in options.

So

```
Backbone.sync('delete', false, {url : "/credit_cards/1", data : ''})
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to do something a bit more custom that doesn't seem to be fitting in with the default Backbone behaviour I would suggest you either override the Sync() function within your model or define a different function where you can define your own Ajax call.

I tend to think of Backbone model functions as a set of sensible defaults that can be overridden when needed rather than a set of functions you must live with.

Scott